# C++ - function select shows there are data in stdin after they were read

Tags: c++, select, stdin

I have following code in my chat client:

```
fd_set fds;
struct timeval t;
t.tv_sec = 0;
t.tv_usec = 100;
int ret;

string message;

while(run)
{
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);

    if((ret = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &t)) < 0)
    {
        exit(ERR_SELECT);
    }
    else if(ret > 0 && FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds))
    {
        message.clear();
        getline(cin, message);

        if(strlen(message.c_str()) > 0)
        {
            send_message(&message, client_socket);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when I type something while program is running. It reads message in stdin, sends it and then wait in loop for next input. But when I pass input to program on start like this:

```
echo "message" | ./chat_client
```

Or this:

```
printf "message\n" | ./chat_client
```

It reads and sends "message" but then in next iterations of loop it behaves like there is something in stdin but `getline` reads only empty string. And then when I write something, `getline` does not read it.

Does anyone know what causes it?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you using C *or* C++? There is no such language as C/C++

Comment: edited to c++ only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) returns if it reaches end-of-file, which happens when everything coming from the pipe has been read. You need to explicitly test if `cin.eof()` returns true.

As for `select()` it's by design that it shows the file as "readable" if at end-of-file. That way the program can detect the connection was closed. The Linux [manual for `select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) states that:

> A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a
>          corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2) without blocking...

and a `read()` on a file descriptor at EOF returns a zero without blocking.

---

I'm not sure if you can get problems by selecting on an fd read through an istream, but this works for me (Linux/gcc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  std::string message;
  while(1) {
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
    int ret = select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret == -1) break;
    getline(std::cin, message);
    if (std::cin.eof()) {
      std::cout << "eof." << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    std::cout << "read: " << message << std::endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I tried using function `getchar` instead of `getline` and read till `EOF` and it still does the same and getchar returns `EOF` in every iteration of main loop. Could you please write exactly where should I test `cin.eof()`? Or how can I make it read whole stdin and then wait again for next input?

Comment: And when I read input and `cin.eof()` is true but I want to read again, how can I get `cin` to be readable again. Because `cin.eof()` returns true after `getline` but I am not able to read from `cin` again.

Comment: @Spook, what do you propose to read after you have already read to the end? With the command you gave: `echo foo | ./prog` all that comes from standard input is the string output by the `echo`. There is nothing else to read. (And since it's a pipe, you can't even seek it backwards.)

Comment: ok, so if I send message from input if it only ends with `'\n'` and somebody runs command: `echo "message1\n message2" | ./prog`, I can only send message1 and end whole program. There is no way user could write new messages while program is running. Is it correct?

Comment: @Spook, of course you could open another file or explicitly read from the terminal regardless of a redirected stdin. But that's a bit of a different matter. Though you could also have the user give something as a command line argument, and then read something else from stdin. But again, I don't think that's directly related.

Comment: But it is exactly what I want but cannot achieve. I want to read input passed to program by echo or printf and then continue reading if user writes something else while program is running. Is it possible and if so, how?